# Place absolute element under sibling

Tags: css

I want to position a custom button element under it's sibling, so that the sibling's shadow effect will be visible on button. Currently the shadow isn't visible on button, but under it. See code snipped to better understand what I mean by that:

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  z-index: 10;
}

.button {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="button">x</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `position: relative;` to `.box` so that it will support the z-index value without effecting the layout.

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Another option is to change `z-index` of .button to `-1`. But it may have other effects in the layout since the element will be positioned behind all other elements.

```
.button {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```